# Is there an ISO language code to indicate mixed-language text?

Tags: nlp, iso

I've checked the [ISO 639-1 specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) but can't find any references. I can just make something up for my database, but was curious if there is a standard.

Update 2012-02-26: I ended up creating a special entry in my languages table with an asterisk (*) as the country code which I now use to represent entries in no single language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [precedence for using commas when storing multiple ISO language codes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-text/), but for a database entry, another table might be prudent when storing such metadata (or even the data itself along with it's language code, if it can be partitioned at the paragraph or even sentence level) to represent such a one to many relationship.

If you are referring to [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation), and you are dealing with multiple languages, then it would be best to convert the text to a [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) charset that your database supports, and store multilingual text in that format.

Answer (score 4):

[ISO 639-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2) and [ISO 639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-3) reserved the code `mul` for documents that contain multiple languages.

By the way, [IETF BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) is currently the most authoritative document on the use of language codes.